# Symfony2 - Import config.yml in services.xml

Tags: php, xml, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml

I am new in Symfony2 and I want to import my config.yml into the services.xml.

*config.yml:*

```
cleverreach:  
   soap:
     key: myApiKey
     url: myWsdlUrl
```

*services.xml:*

```
<parameters>
  <parameter key="key">getKey</parameter>
  <parameter key="url">getUrl</parameter>
</parameters>
```

I don't know how I can give the variables to the services.xml... 
Here is the PHP code I use to parse the config.yml and to load the services.xml:

```
    $appPath = dirname(__DIR__);
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($appPath));
    $loader->load('services.xml');

    // todo@all parse yml, add params to container
    $load = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($appPath . '/Config'));

    $yaml_config_file = $appPath . '/Config/Config.yml';
    $parsed_yml_file = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($yaml_config_file));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension method gets `ContainerBuilder` and an config array. It is strongly recommended that you use [Configuration class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html) to process it before usage, but technically, you can access it without it (do var_dump or debug $config array that you received as method parameter).

After you extract variables the way you want, you want to do:

```
$container->setParameter('parametername', $parameterValue);
```

And after it you can load 'services.yml' and use it, for example:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: %parametername%
```